# Android custom list view and Adapter not working

Tags: java, android

Hi i am new to android development and i ia m trying to build a custom list view with firebase realtime database and i am following this tutorial [here](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-arrayadapter-tutorial-example.html) but in my project there is unexpected error  like this:

[image: my error screenshoot]

**My Activity Code**

```
  public class Notification extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView simpleList;
    ArrayList<Item> animalList=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.winnerslist);
        animalList.add(new Item("Lion",R.drawable.sunil));
        animalList.add(new Item("Tiger",R.drawable.ic_user));


        MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.winnerslist,animalList);
        simpleList.setAdapter(myAdapter);





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                backToHome();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        backToHome();
    }
    public void backToHome() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Notification.this, MainActivity.class);
        Notification.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }






}
```

**My Adopter**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClipData.Item> {

    ArrayList<ClipData.Item> animalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ClipData.Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        animalList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.winnerslist, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView.setText("ffff");
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunil);
        return v;

    }

}
```

above is my code for activity and adopter  please review this where i am doing wrong i followed tutorial exactly what they explain there but still getting error
and this stackoverflowis telling me to add more text just because i am showing more code but there is nothing i can say.

Comment: Share you activity and adapter code as text not as image

Comment: post your adapter code as well

Comment: First and Foremost `ListView` is deprecated. Read of RecyclerView here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: run the code and post your error log as well.

Comment: The Item type is mismatched.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Remove this import

```
import android.content.ClipData;
```

> and use your Item Object import.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    ArrayList<Item> animalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        animalList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return animalList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.winnerslist, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView.setText("ffff");
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunil);
        return v;

    }

}
```

Comment: hi thanks your code is working can u also please help me how can i use data from firebase realtime  database instead of using this " animalList"

Comment: @Anilmeena just put another question for that. If your problem solved accept answer which helped you.

Comment: its not allowing me to add new question can you please help here do i need to use RecyclerView or something else what i need to do is show a list and data is coming from firebase databse not this array list

Comment: you can use RecyclerView and i really didn't work on firebase. So i have less knowladage about firebase for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ClipData from your adapter's 3rd parameter or Use this

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        animalList = objects;
    }
```

Please check error carefully

[image: Your Error Says]

Adapter construstor wants 3rd paramater as `Clipdata.Item` as your counstrustor

```
 public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, **ArrayList<ClipData.Item> objects**) {
```

And the parameter your are passing in this  `ArrayList<Item> animalList`

so please remove clipdata from your adapter as i said at starting of my answer